# "...herd of whales..." - "...стадо китів..."?

Tags: переклад, from-english, вживання-слів

Побачив у перекладі "Фоліо" цю фразу. Знаю, що їм не можна довіряти.

Подивився у [SUM](http://sum.in.ua/s/stado), здається, що дійсно не варто вірити, бо тут більше про сільське господарство і орґанізовані людиною речі.

Чи правильно розумію, що "[зграя](http://sum.in.ua/s/zghraja) китів" звучить і семантично підходить набагато краще?

Comment: Для англійської є [отаке](//en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-do-you-call-a-group-of) — було б добре мати аналогічний мінідовідник для української.

Comment: @Sasha було б. Можна створити вікіпитання і віківідповідь, де колективно перекладемо все це. До того ж, треба пам’ятати, що оксфорд - це британський словник.

Comment: Ну, тут питання в якості/надійності результату. Давайте спочатку про китів виришімо :).

Comment: @Sasha davajte)

Comment: @Sasha, бачите, пан follower яку розлогу відповідь зробив? Думаю, він сам у змозі перекласти всі ці англійські терміни, а якщо взятися разом, то точно зможемо. Тут є якесь "напів-вікі", щоби змодерувати, якщо що?

Comment: Наскільки я знаю, напів-вікі нема.

Comment: @Sasha в будь-якому разі є bytebuster, він зможе регулювати все це. Треба зробити широке питання про стада, зграї, табуни, ватаги і т.д. І все це структурувати, щоби будь-хто міг прийти і швидко скористатися без 1000 годин пошуків правильного слова.

Comment: Чи ми могли б за результатами одразу зробити отаке українською: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names ? І треба питати не лише мовознавців, а й зоологів.

Comment: Залежно від того, про яких китів іде мова правильними можуть бути обидва варіанти. Зграя, зазвичай, (особливо у відношенні до ссавців) вживається щодо хижих видів - зграя собак/вовків/гієн (іноді мишей). Тож у відношенні до косаток слово зграя буде правильнішим, можливо й щодо інших дельфінячих так само...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Словники

> <sup>[Загальний народний англійсько-український словник](http://e2u.org.ua/dicts/common)</sup>
>   [herd](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=herd&dicts=1&highlight=on)
>
> 1. стадо, [череда](http://sum.in.ua/s/chereda), [табун](http://sum.in.ua/s/tabun), [гурт](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghurt)
> 2. *зневажл.* натовп, юрма, юрба
>
> herd instinct — стадний інстинкт, стадне чуття

---

> <sup>[Українсько-англійський словник 1955р.](http://e2u.org.ua/dicts/andrusyshen) (Андрусишин, Крет)</sup>
>   [herd](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=herd&dicts=8&highlight=on)
>
> - [вата́га](http://sum.in.ua/s/vatagha)
> - гурт
> - [згін](http://sum.in.ua/s/zghin)ь (згонь)
> - [отара](http://sum.in.ua/s/otara)
> - [паства](http://sum.in.ua/s/pastva)
> - стадо
> - табун
> - череда

Якщо переглянути тлумачний словник, то ці слова майже тотожні між собою.

---

### Науковий погляд

> <sup>Викіпедія ¬ [Китоподібні ⇒ Спосіб життя](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%96#.D0.A1.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.96.D0.B1_.D0.B6.D0.B8.D1.82.D1.82.D1.8F)</sup>
>   Більшість видів — стадні тварини; тримаються групами від кількох до сотень і тисяч голів.

Також англомовна стаття [*Herd*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd) відсилає до відповідної статті [*Стадо*.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE)

---

> <sup>Основи популяційної екологія ¬ [Етологічна структура популяцій тварин](http://subject.com.ua/ecology/population/26.html)</sup>
>   Ускладнення поведінкових звʼязків між особинами популяції сприяло формуванню більших обʼєднань тварин — зграї, стада, табуни, колонії.
>
> **Колонії** — це групові поселення осілих тварин. Вони можуть бути тимчасові, або періодичні (на період розмноження), або довготривалі. Будучи простими скупченнями поодиноких особин певного виду, *колонії функціонують як цілісний організм, де окремі члени, подібно як органи, виконують певні життєві функції.*
>
> **Зграї** — це тимчасові обʼєднання тварин, які полегшують виконання будь-яких життєвих функцій виду (міграції, добування їжі, захисту від ворогів). Зграї характерні для риб, птахів деяких видів ссавців (собачих).
>
> За способами координації дії зграї поділяються на дві категорії:
>
> 1. зграї без вираженого домінування окремих членів (без лідерів);
> 2. зграї з лідерами, в яких тварини орієнтуються на поведінку однієї або кількох найдосвідченіших особин.
>
> **Стада (табуни)** — це тривалі і постійніші обʼєднання тварин (ссавців). Основу групової поведінки тварин в стадах становлять взаємовідносини **домінування-підлеглості**. *Стадо підкоряється лідеру, як найдосвідченішому члену і діє як єдине ціле. Біологічне значення лідерства полягає в тому, що індивідуальний досвід окремих особин може бути використаний усією групою. Діяльність лідера не спрямована безпосередньо на підлеглість інших особин.*
>
> Найскладнішою є організація **стад з вожаками** (у слонів, табуни у коней) та **ієрархічним підпорядкуванням особин**. *На відміну від лідерів, вожаки характеризуються поведінкою, безпосередньо спрямованою на активне керівництво стадом спеціальними сигналами, погрозами та прямим нападом. Ранг кожної особини в стаді визначається залежно від віку, фізичної сили, досвіду і спадкових якостей тварини.*

---

### Приклади

> <sup>[Фрагменти-приклади з Google Books](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&tbm=bks)</sup>
>   Її увагу привернуло **стадо китів**, що пливли до узбережжя, щоб народити дитинчат у теплих водах. ¬ [*Світло між двох океанів*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Yk00CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT9&dq=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiog5-m9KTVAhXKCJoKHZ_sB2cQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&f=false)
>
> Коли ж вони натрапляють на **стадо китів**, всі зусилля спрямовані тільки на те, щоб забити якомога більше тварин. ¬ [*Дніпро*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=yzYrAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&dq=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiog5-m9KTVAhXKCJoKHZ_sB2cQ6AEINDAC)
>
> Сильний вітер, шторми заважають знаходити **стадо китів**. ¬ [*Журбина криниця*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vAAYAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&dq=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiog5-m9KTVAhXKCJoKHZ_sB2cQ6AEIOjAD)
>
> Майже повністю винищено **стадо китів**, збідніло багато високопродуктивних районів промислу. ¬ [*Вісник*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=PA-FAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&dq=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiog5-m9KTVAhXKCJoKHZ_sB2cQ6AEIQDAE)
>
> Я побачив на сході велике **стадо китів**; ¬ [*Мобі Дік, або Білий Кит*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=DUNGBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT375&dq=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiog5-m9KTVAhXKCJoKHZ_sB2cQ6AEILDAB)
>
> Сказав би: **гурт китів** заліг на мілині ¬ [*Аюдаг*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=jc9GAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&dq=%22%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJuda3gqXVAhXDJJoKHefXBq4Q6AEIJTAA)
>
> Коли китобої натрапляють на **табун китів**, усі їхні зусилля спрямовані на те, щоб вразити якомога більше тварин.  ¬ [*В краю невидимок*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=UWohAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BD%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&dq=%22%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BD%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuhOXogqXVAhUJCpoKHQndCfAQ6AEIJTAA)
>
> Капітан Немо слідив очима за **ватагою китів** віддалених одну милю від Навтілюса. ¬ [*Сорок тисяч миль під водою*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=m3JCAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2&dq=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjap--hg6XVAhXkNJoKHTzSCoEQ6AEIJzAA)

---

> <sup>Інше</sup>
>   Такий гак і такий канат витримають ціла **череда китів** ¬ [*Пророцтво Вали*](https://sagaolyneone.wordpress.com/page/4/)

Comment: Тобто, найкраще підходить таки "стадо", бо у китів воно не тимчасове? Можете додати щось від себе? Висновки якісь абощо? Бо вікіпедія - сумнівне джерело, а зі статті можна зрозуміти, але краще з висновком.

Comment: Зроблено. Так влаштовує?

Comment: Перепрошую, але схоже, що я не взмозі зупинитися. Додав більше джерел: словники й до них деякі приклади з літератури. Тепер ви можете використовувати також слова-синоніми й більше доказів, що кити складу стада.

Answer (score 4):

Насправді, мені з прикладів наведених у СУМ, видно що "[зграя](http://sum.in.ua/s/zghraja)" це якась швидка група:

"Вороння цілими зграями налітає на баштан", "Хмара бризок і зграя жаб приснули на всі боки", "Ганяли зграї собак, голодних, худих, сердитих", "Полова, немов зграя дрібних блідо-жовтих метеликів, стрімко зривалася з сита..."

Єдиний більш-менш статичний приклад про зграю птахів, що збирається відлітати, проте, звуки цих пташиних зграй долинають з неба, а отже ці птахи також знаходяться у польоті: "Високе небо.. слало на землю тихі шуми: то шелест вітру, то сюрчання пташиних зграй, що збиралися відлітати".

У переносних значеннях мені здалося що можна розбити на дві групи - порівняння із зграєю птахів (зграя гір у хмарах, зграя мрій, зграя срібних звуків), або вовків/собак (військові загони, банди, загони ворогів).

---

Тепер щодо слова [стадо](http://sum.in.ua/s/stado): "// Взагалі велика група яких-небудь тварин, птахів, риб і т. ін., які тримаються разом". Коцюбинський, Франко, Леся Українка вживають це слово для таких тварин:

> У однім величезнім лісі жило стадо Слонів *(Іван Франко)*
>   то пролетіло над ними стадо якихсь птахів, може, диких гусей *(Михайло Коцюбинський)*
>   Жовті кози стадами бродять по вулицях *(Михайло Коцюбинський)*
>   На небі чорна тьма.. По небі стада хмар *(Іван Франко)*
>   Ідуть, ідуть хлопці, самий цвіт, молоді парубки. Ідуть, мов стадо, неначе не знають, куди, на що *(Леся Українка)*

Тобто стадо це або сільськогосподарські тварини, або повільні тварини (як слони, або навіть хмари у Франка), або (у порівняннях) - ті що не мають власної мети та пересуваються виконуючи волю інших (люди, хмари, які жене вітер).

Отже, як на мене, "зграя" для китів не дуже підходить, бо вони 1) не швидкі та 2) дуже великі тварини.

Comment: добре, зграя не підходить, а що підходить? стадо? у франка не зграї, а стада хмар, наприклад.

Comment: http://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE&t=0 отут кажуть, що зграя риб або птахів. Хто правий? Чи кити - не риби, а ссавці - тому стадо?

Comment: Зграя риб - нормально як на мене - маленькі прудкі тваринки, як пташки :) Думаю що стадо, так.

Comment: добре, дякую, в іншій відповіді бачите - навіть якась наукова праця підійшла на доказ.